# Make entity's constructor private

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I would like to prevent my clients from instantiating entities through the constructor.
As there's quite a bit of pluming involved to create those entities (initialise states, collections etc...), and WCF doesn't work that way, I would like instead to force them to call a method on the server side that will create the entity and send it over the wire, something like

Client side:

```
var client = EntityServiceClient("myEndpoint");
var newEntity = client.CreateEntity();
```

Server side:

```
public Entity CreateEntity()
{
    return new Entity();
}
```

I have something working, but I would like to somehow throw an exception when the default constructor of the entity is used, or make it private. So the following should not work

Client side:

```
var client = EntityServiceClient("myEndpoint");
var newEntity = new Entity();
```

Is it something possible?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Can you be more specific? =(

Comment: make your entity class private.

Comment: A class not need to have a default ctor.  And you can use an internal ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really how WCF is designed to work, the serialised objects as far as the client are concerned only contain data not behaviour so you should send back DTO's not entities.

However if you insist on going with this approach which will most likely cause you trouble in the future, you can move your objects & service interface into a separate class library and distribute it instead of having clients generate the code from meta data when adding a service reference.

Comment: Totally see your point, and indeed that's not the way I want to go.

Answer (score 1):

The class at the client side is (usually) a generated proxy. Not the same class as at the server side, just a mock up.

In any case, the deserializer at the client needs to be able to re-create entities. The DataContractSerializer simply ignores your private constructors and creates its own.

The situation changes slightly when you use a library with shared types. The best you could do then is to make the ctors `internal` and add the Factory to the library as well.

All in all I think this is not a good idea. Remmber, he aim of WCF is to exchanges *data*, not *objects*.

Comment: That's not fully accurate, while it does not call your constructor, it doesn't actually create one itself it calls  FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type) to create the instance without calling a constructor or field initialisers.

Comment: @TrevorPilley - client code will be able to do `var p = new ClassWithPrivateCtor();`.

Comment: Yes if the classes are generated from the meta data, I was not suggesting otherwise I was correcting your statement about the data contract serialiser creating its own constructor.

Comment: Again, I totally see your point too, and yes, I realise the question is unclear, but your remark and Trevor's before got me thinking and I think I know what I should have asked myself in the first place.
I guess the real question I need to answer first is do I really need this serialisation process between those 2 layers...

Answer (score 0):

You question is really unclear to me - anyway I try to help you and give you some tips.
In your case, I think a kind of factory is a good approach.

Define a `EntityServiceClient` and `Entity` in the server side assembly. Note, the access modifier will prevent here the instantiating of an `Entity` through the constructor:

```
public class EntityServiceClient
{

    public EntityServiceClient(string endpoint)
    {
      // put here initializing code for your service client.
    }

    public Entity CreateEntity()
    {
        return new Entity(); // May here put your complexe code to initializing a new valid entity
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    internal Entity()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: But should this be a server or client-side factory? Or both?

Comment: Thats depends on the architecture of the client-server. In the question it's really unclear where is what...

Comment: Sorry my code was unclear, I missed a "new" at the creation of the client which should read `var client = new EntityServiceClient("endpointName");`
Asking myself what i drunk that day...